# javascript async/await and promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm having a hard time understanding how async/await works.I have to make a program which contains three functions: `func1` `func2` and `concatenated`.
`func1` takes a string as an argument and returns the same string after 5 seconds of delay, `func2` is an `async` function which also takes a string as an argument and returns the same string. `concatenated` is a function that takes two strings `(s1,s2)` as arguments and uses the above two functions(`(func1(s1) and func2(s2))`) to return their concatenated result after 5 seconds. So if we pass `("hello"," world")` to `concatenated` it should return `hello world`. My code is:

```
function func1(x) {
return new Promise(resolve => {
setTimeout(() => {
  resolve(x);
    }, 5000);
  });
 }

async function func2(x) {
const a = await func1(x);
return a;
}

function concatenated(a,b){
  const c = func2(a).then(result =>{console.log(result)});
  const d = func2(b).then(result =>{console.log(result)});
  return (c+d) ;
} 

concatenated("hello"," world")
```

This code only gives me:
`hello
  world`

How can I correct this?

Comment: Why does your `concatenated` function not use `await`, but rather `then`? Notice that `c` and `d` are both promises (for `undefined`, the results of the callbacks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your return statement from the `concatenated` function will be run **synchronously**. This also means that `c` and `d` will still be promises.

A possible solution would be:

```
async function concatenated(a,b){
  const c = await func2(a);
  const d = await func2(b);

  return (c+d);
} 

concatenated("hello", " world").then(result => {
    console.log(result); // hello world
})
```

Notice that an **async function** will always return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result after 5 seconds like this:

```js
function func1(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 5000);
  });
 }

async function func2(x) {
  const a = await func1(x);
  return a;
}

async function concatenated(a,b){
  const [c,d] = await Promise.all([func2(a), func2(b)])
  return c+d;
}

(async function main() {
  const ret = await concatenated("hello"," world")
  console.log(ret)
})()
```

Using JavaScript `async/await` syntax, you can write the asynchronous code like the synchronous style. No need `promise.then`, no need callback. It's a little different from other languages, e.g. Go, Java

Answer (score -2):

You seem to be misunderstanding console logs. A regular `console.log` will always put a newline, which is why you are seeing hello world on two lines rather than one. Assuming you are using Node.js, you can use the following to write to the console without a newline to achieve your desired outcome:

`process.stdout.write(result);`