# 'await' call doesn't wait

Tags: javascript, async-await

My app is trying to upload files to S3. S3 upload works fine. The problem is that after imageUpload returns, in handleSubmit(), it claims that the return value for imageUpload() is undefined. I suspect that it has to do with async/await, which I'm not too familiar with.
Can any expert explain what I'm missing?

```
  async function imageUpload() {
 
    const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: product.media.name,
      Body: product.media
    };
    s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
        if (s3Err) throw s3Err
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`) // successfully get data.Location here
        return data.Location
    });

  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();
      setLoading(true)
      setError('')
      const mediaUrl = await imageUpload()

      const url = `${baseUrl}/api/product`

      const { name, desc } = product
      const payload = { name, desc, mediaUrl } // mediaUrl is undefined here
      
      const response = await axios.post(url, payload)

    } catch(error) {
      catchErrors(error, setError)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `imageUpload()` function returns nothing (there is no return statement in the function therefore it returns undefined). If you want to wait for `s3.upload` you will need to convert it to a promise - and there are plenty of answers for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript async/await and promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222364/javascript-async-await-and-promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your imageUpload code inside promise and then pass the data to resolve callback that you want to return, and if there is some error you pass them in reject callback, throwing error in asynchronous task can give unexpected behaviour, so use reject callback there.

```
async function imageUpload() {

    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: product.media.name,
        Body: product.media
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
            if (s3Err) {
                reject(s3Error);
            }
            
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`) // successfully get data.Location here
            resolve(data.Location);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `s3.upload` is in an async function, but using a callback, and only returning to the callback (not to the outer function in any way). The AWS SDKs for JS all (or mostly all) support Promises now, so you should be able to do this:

```
async function imageUpload() {
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: product.media.name,
    Body: product.media
  };

  const data = await s3.upload(params).promise()
  console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
  return data
}
```

Comment: [`s3.upload()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) returns a [`ManagedUpload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html), which has a [`promise()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#promise-property) method, so the correct way to write it is `const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();`. Also don't catch the error, allow the caller to handle it since `imageUpload()` shouldn't be error handling.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you, I'll edit my answer with your corrections.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your imageUpload function. You do not tell it to wait for response from s3.upload

```
 function imageUpload() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
           Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
           Key: product.media.name,
           Body: product.media
        };
        s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
           if (s3Err) reject(s3Err)
           else resolve(data.Location)
        
        });

    });

  }
```